# Looping Watchpack error (watcher): \ Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory after npm run dev

Tags: typescript, ubuntu, next.js, wsl-2

I am pretty new to coding, and I am trying to run next.js on wsl:ubuntu on vsc. But when I created a directory and trying to run npm run dev, the error [Watchpack error (watcher):

```
 \ Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory after npm run dev watch  '\\wsl$Ubuntu\<PATH>
```

after running `npm` run `dev`, keeps running on my terminal, I searched through the internet and could not find one solution to help.

I have tried every solution possible on [NPM stuck giving the same error EISDIR: Illegal operation on a directory, read at error (native)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34959038/npm-stuck-giving-the-same-error-eisdir-illegal-operation-on-a-directory-read-a)
and I looked at [Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, readlink 'D:\study\noobinjs\pages\_app.tsx' when trying to run 'npm run build' for next js app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71491493/error-eisdir-illegal-operation-on-a-directory-readlink-d-study-noobinjs-pag) but i dont think it is applicable to me since i am on ubuntu
But none of them works. Anyone that could help would be really appreciated...

my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "project-name",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "^14.0.4",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "20.10.5",
    "@types/react": "18.2.45",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.0.4",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3"
  }
}
```